# What is the most efficient way to check for a sequence of numbers in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

### Background

For a technical interview I was tasked with implementing a missing algorithm in JavaScript. The interviewer supplied me with some code and 18 failing unit tests that once the algorithm was successfully implemented would pass. I'm sure there is a more efficient way to have solved this problem as I tried a few different approaches during my allotted time. This way is the first way that I got to work, which for the technical test was enough but I'd like to know a better way of solving the problem.

### Problem

Work out if the cards in a poker hand form a straight. (I've already ordered the hand in ascending order.)

### My Solution

```
PokerHand.prototype._check_straight_function = function(arr) {
    var isStraight = false;
    for (var j = i = 4; i >= 0 && j > 1; i--)
        if (arr[i].value() - 1 == arr[--j].value()) {
            isStraight = true;
        } else {
            isStraight = false;
        }
    };
    return isStraight;
};
```

### Other approaches

Things I didn't get working that I think *might* work faster, I'd really appreciate if someone could talk me through a working version of the below approach(es) and help me understand which is the fastest to evaluate.

- recursive use of `arr.pop().value - 1 == arr.pop().value()`
- `filter` the array to create a new array that contains only values where the next index (`arr[++i])`is the current index + 1 and then see if the new array is the same length.
- a `for loop` with a `break / continue` to short circuit as soon as the straight ends.

Comment: are the cards in the hand sorted?

Comment: Looks like your question might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @StinePike yes, per the line (I've already sorted the cards in ascending order)

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I'm not asking for a review of my approach, I'm asking for alternative implmentations. i.e code I haven't written, if you want to get this moved though feel free to flag it.

Comment: Forgive me for asking , but Is your current code really working? As I see it the only thing that must be true is that the last last array item and the array item before?

Comment: I realize that you are looking for a new approach that may be "better" than the current one, however it looks like the current approach is incorrect. It looks like your code will return true as long as any 2 elements are one more than the last, ie, 2,3,5,8,9 would return true because 2,3

Comment: The code is incorrect because it will assign isStraight (or clear it) only for the given pair being checked. Thus the "last pair" incorrectly determines the result.

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld - I guess, therein lies the problem of TDD. You're code is only as good as the unit tests. I've fixed this error but the actual question still remains.

Comment: Because the array is already ordered, we know that a necessary condition to have a straight is that the difference between the first card value and the last card value is exactly four. You may have a global performance gain by adding this test if you have a large number of arrays to check and most of them are not passing it. Side note : if we know that all cards have distinct values, it becomes a *sufficient* condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>The [original] code is incorrect because it will assign `isStraight` (or clear it) only for the given pair being checked. Thus the "last pair" incorrectly determines the result.</del>

In my book the "better way", is to keep it clean:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var a = arr[i];   // arr[0..3]
    var b = arr[i+1]; // arr[1..4]
    if (!(a.value() + 1 == b.value())) {
        return false; // Not sequential
    }
};
return true;
```

If a `zip` higher-order function is available this could be reduced as a variation of

```
arr.zip(function (a, b) { return [a.value(), b.value()] })
   .every(function (x) { return x[0] + 1 === x[1] })
```

but `zip` is not standard.

Comment: This is not an answer. This should be placed as a comment.

Comment: I've fixed the error, this was down to me writing code to pass the tests rather than tackling the problem. :$ I do like the idea of a higher order function though.

Comment: I like the `!` negation of `a.value() +1 == b.value()` its nice and clear. +1

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to assign a variable isStraight at all.

```
PokerHand.prototype._check_straight_function = function(arr) {
    for (var i = i = 4; i++) {        
        if (arr[i].value() - 1 != arr[i-1].value()) {
            return false;
        }
    };

    return true;
};
```

Comment: so the `return false` would short circuit the loop as soon as the straight sequence was broken. That I like. I guess just returning the condition would work too? That's maybe wrongly assuming that returning `true == continue` and `false == break`

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by returning the condition? return true would be like continue and false would be like "break" yes. (depending on the rest of your code)

Comment: I mean could you just return the value of the `if` inside the for loop? e.g. 

`return arr[i].value() - 1 == arr[i-1].value()`

  assuming the loop will continue if the return value is true and short circuit when the condition is false.

Comment: I don't understand. What value do you want to return (and why) ?

Comment: I mean if returning false will short circuit the loop and returning true will continue it, do you need the if statement?

Comment: The if statement is needed to check if the conditions tells "Is this NOT a sequence of ordered number? - then return false..." If it is a ordered number sequence - it would continue the for-loop. It returns true AFTER the for-loop because then we are sure that ALL of the items in the array are ordered in ascending numbered order.  So YES, false would short the  circuit the loop and returning true will continue it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91553/discussion-between-luke-and-bestprogrammerintheworld).

Answer (score 2):

Just throwing it out there, I think this one does it with the least amount of lines (3), whether or not that is "better" is subjective as it is probably less clear

```
    var last = arr.pop().value(), popped;
    while ((popped = arr.pop().value()) === --last);
    return popped === undefined;
```

Comment: Not so readable, but cool implementation and actually an alternative :-)

Comment: thanks! its a little crazy looking for sure but it uses pop like OP was wondering about, and I rarely get to use a loop with no body so I enjoyed using one here

Comment: I like this, thanks. I assumed a pop implementation would look similar.

Answer (score 1):

here is a similar code with some minor optimization ( in java,, check the algorithm)

```
    boolean isStraight = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (arr[i] + 1 != arr[i+1]) {
            isStraight = false;
            break;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is maybe a tiny bit tidier.  I don't see a Ninja way ;(  As far as comparing the solutions -- I'm an employer, and for my part, I'd prefer the answer which was clear and elegant over one which was a few nanoseconds faster :)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  if (a[i].value() != i + a[0].value())
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

here is another way

```js
var isOrdered = true;
[5, 6, 8, 9].sort(function(a, b) {
  (b - a != 1) ? isOrdered = false: true;
});
alert(isOrdered);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uksghvo8/)

Comment: This is entirely incorrect.